# Как разметить меню

Tags: css3, html5

как разметить меню таким образом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем особенность?

Comment: Впредь при публикации вопросов, вызывающих затруднения, старайтесь прикладывать свой вариант решения этого вопроса, чтобы другие участники могли исправить ошибки или понять ваш подход к решению задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблицей или div-блоками с помощью flexbox или grid разметкой, или float выравниванием